# Record HTML input range value only once dragging is stopped

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to call the function only when the dragging of Input Range is stopped?

```
state={
  range:500
}

changeHandle=(e)=>{
   const range=e.currentTarget.value;
   this.setState({range});
   this.connectToServer(range);  //call this function only when dragging is stopped
}

connectToServer=async(value)=>{
    await axios.............
}
```

HTML

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.range} type="range" step="500" min="500" max="10000" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to prevent hitting the API over and over again. Actually there is another solution for this, which is using `debounce` function.

TLDR; what debounce doing is delaying the function calling by such duration.
I assume that you're using reactJS, so you can achieve it like this using lodash

```js
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

export default function App() {
  const debounceFunc = debounce((val) => handleChange(val), 500)

  const handleChange = val => {
    console.log(val)
    // hit API here
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max={100}
        onChange={e => {
          debounceFunc(e.target.value)
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can try it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-snowflake-xsx31?file=/src/App.js) on codesandbox.
And this is the [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)

There is also another way using debounce, by creating custom hooks `useDebounce`. If you're interested on it, you can check it [here](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/)

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't want to hammer your endpoint with all the extraneous intermediate `onChange` values, so you basically need to debounce the input's `onChange` handler.

Here's a simple debounce utility I occasionally use:

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timerId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), delay);
  };
};
```

But any 3rd-party package like lodash would work.

The next steps are key, you don't want to block the state updates so you'll want to split out the state update from the server call.

You want to issue the side-effect of calling your backend in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method for two reasons.

1. It's the correct method for side-effects.
2. It ensures you have the latest `this.state.range` value

Code:

```
connectToServer = (value) => console.log("Send to server", value);
debouncedConnectToServer = debounce(this.connectToServer, 500);

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.range !== this.state.range) {
    this.debouncedConnectToServer(this.state.range);
  }
}

handleChange = (e) => {
  const range = e.currentTarget.value;
  this.setState({ range });
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit record-html-input-range-value-only-once-dragging-is-stopped]

Full demo code:

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timerId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), delay);
  };
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    range: 500
  };

  connectToServer = (value) => console.log("Send to server", value);
  debouncedConnectToServer = debounce(this.connectToServer, 500);

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.range !== this.state.range) {
      this.debouncedConnectToServer(this.state.range);
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const range = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({ range });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <label>
        Input
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.range}
          type="range"
          step="500"
          min="500"
          max="10000"
        />
      </label>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OnMouseUp worked for me

```
 <input type='range' min="10" max="120" value={range} 
      onChange={({target}) => {
         setRange(target.value)
      }}
      onMouseUp={(e) => {
         console.log(range)
      }}
  />
```